# Get value from element only if a tag contains a string

Tags: jquery, find

```
<span id="restmap9" class="taLnk hvrIE6" onclick="...">Map</span>1
```

I want to get the `onclick` value from this type on code but only if the `id` contains `restmap`.

I tried with this code:

```
if($(v).find('span.taLnk:contains("restmap")').length)2
```

But it doesn't work.

1. I can't change this code and can't use the classes as they are
   used in another part of the website.
2. `$(v)` is my source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do like this:

```
if($(v).find('[id~="restmap"].taLnk').length)
```

Comment: +1 It's clearer than mine in fact. (maybe `~=` instead of `^=` though if OP wants "contains")

Comment: I wrote "maybe", because the example makes it look like it's really `/^restmap\d+$/` so it's possible ^= would be more suited...

Comment: Another way could be: if($('[id~="restmap"].taLnk', $(v)).length)

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of search over a set of elements with a precise non standard condition, you may use `filter` :

```
if ($('.taLnk',v).filter(function(){
    return /^restmap\d+$/.test(this.id)
}).length) {
```

Comment: +1: This is the better way for case-insensitive matching too (if you have `/i` on the regex of course)

Comment: Thanks destroy for your solution too.